# In R, how do I generate r random sample of contiguous polygons?

Tags: r

I'm trying to find a way of generating sample of contiguous polygons.

This code correctly generates sample of 5% of original data.

```
library(sf)
library(tmap)
tmap_mode("view")

nc <- read_sf(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))

nc %>% 
  qtm()

sample <- st_sample(nc, 
                    size = round(nrow(nc)*0.05), 
                    type = "random") 
sample %>% 
  qtm()

st_join(nc, st_sf(sample), 
        join = st_intersects, 
        left = FALSE) %>% 
  qtm(borders = "purple", fill = NULL)
```

However the polygons are (correctly) all over the map. Is there a way to constrain them to be spatially (queen) contiguous?

I could probably start with one random polygon, find neighbours and repeat the process until n% of polygons are in the set. If however there is a simpler and more elegant way to do it I will totally not object to using it.

Comment: Could you please provide a visual example of your desired end-product? I have never heard of Queen contiguous.

Comment: @Aaron https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/172998/queen-vs-rook-neighborhood or https://www.biomedware.com/files/documentation/clusterseer/Concepts/Polygon_contiguity.htm#:~:text=Two%20options%20are%20available%E2%80%94rook,the%20movements%20of%20chess%20pieces.&text=Thus%2C%20rook%20is%20a%20more,as%20small%20as%20one%20point.

Comment: Thanks for edit @Vince - wasn't aware that winks have been banned ;)

Comment: There's too many ways to do this. You could start with all the cells filled, pick one, and remove it and try another one *if* it disconnects the filled cells, repeat until 5% left. That will be a different process to picking a cell and then adding random connected cells. Clarify if you want either suggestions for processes or if you want a specific process coded (in R).

Comment: (I mean "polygons" for "cells" in the above comment. I had a raster on the brain - but the same comment applies)

Comment: Another possibility is that there are  n-choose-m ways of selecting m polygons from n, and of those n, a subset p are connected. Generate all members of p and select one uniformly. I think that's the "most random" I can think of, but the combinatorics work against you for any medium sized  data set.

Comment: Thank you @Spacedman! I can imagine your solutions working in theory - but having hard time to translate that into code so any starting points would be welcome!

Comment: I don't want to waste our time coding up algorithms that you don't need. Have you looked at creating adjacency matrices with functions in the `spdep` package and maybe seeing if they map to connected graphs using the `igraph` package? Actually this does boil down to a graph theory question...

Comment: https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03610910902807854 might have the algorithm you want...

Comment: Thanks! working on the solution based on hints from @mdsumner https://gist.github.com/mdsumner/b727f1051209897b99321c20989ec346

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This function uses the `igraph` and `spdep` and `sf` packages:

```
connectUp <- function(polys, n){
    nb = spdep::poly2nb(polys)
    g = igraph::graph.adjlist(nb)

    selected = sample(nrow(polys),1)

    while(length(selected) < n){
        nbrs = unlist(igraph::ego(g, 1, selected, mindist=1))
        newnbrs = setdiff(nbrs, selected)
        selected = c(selected, sample(newnbrs,1))
    }
    return(selected)
}
```

Here's a test function:

```
test <- function(){
    nc = sf::st_read(system.file("gpkg/nc.gpkg", package = "sf"))
    connected = connectUp(nc, 10)
    plot(nc$geom)
    plot(nc$geom[connected], add=TRUE, col="red")
}
```

When you run it you should see the North Carolina map with 10 connected regions in red. Here's 9 runs:

[image]

It looks like there's a disconnected part in the last one, but its because that county includes the very thin islands which are connected to another county in the North.

Adjust the `poly2nb` call to select any different adjacency definition you might want to try.

This algorithm picks a initial region at random, then adds neighbours to the selected set randomly one at a time to the selected set, repeats until enough regions in the selected set. The key function is `igraph::ego`.

I doubt it is selecting uniformly randomly from the set of N-connected region sets, but that looks hard.

Comment: Hi @Spacedeman. I'm having problem replicating that with another dataset (US counties). What might be causing a failure with a message `Error in igraph::graph.adjlist(nb) : At structure_generators.c:86 : Invalid (negative) vertex id, Invalid vertex id`

Comment: Tracked down the problem. There were two counties with no neighbours. Removing them from input data fixed the problem.

Comment: Great answer! Will bookmark this