# Unable to use the tool "difference" after the tool "clip"

Tags: qgis, geometry, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler

I have stumbled on an error and I would like to have an external point of view to maybe help me figure it out.

When I

1. clip `layerA` as input with `layerB` as the overlay, and then
2. make the difference of `layerC` as input with the `Clipped` layer as the overlay layer,

I get this error:

> Could not add feature with geometry type MultiLineString to layer
> of type MultiPolygon

Strangely, all of the layers are multipolygons.

I then tried to do `mutlipart to singlepart` + `remove duplicate vertices` + `fix geometries`, but the issue still arise. I even tried to do a tiny negative buffer to make very small objects disapear.

Any other idea to circumvent this situation?

Here is a link to the gpkg containing the layers : https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1TpPflqDJGYriDaYcjr49F04qpk9uXsPw?usp=share_link

I use Windows11 and QGIS 3.28.6

Comment: I'd load the clipped data into a geopandas dataframe, filter out the Multistring geom types and then save to another shapefile. That will let you zoom to the feature that is causing the error.

Comment: I've run into problems sometimes where you linestrings are generated due to corner shared [geometries](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/172998/queen-vs-rook-neighborhood).

Comment: So I understand that the clip creates some undesired artifacts. The thing is, this step is part of a big model, is there a way to filter lines with the basic processes ? (I'm using the model and not a python script because it will be shared with a client)

Comment: Please provide more details: which is input layer, which is overlay layer? In step 2, you use the clipped layer for difference tool? Again: which layer is input and overlay? Simply following your steps, I get no error.

Comment: You don't have to use a python script, just one easier way of identifying errors sometimes. But to echo Babel, I too cannot reproduce your error.

Comment: I've edited my question now

Comment: @Elyum I see that you have a few answers below that may work. It seems that layerC is parcel data. After looking through your data I did come across a strange geometry (class NoneType. You should take a look at `id==27`. You may have some problems with that later down the road with further processing.

Comment: @Binx how on earth did you see that? It is indeed solved with the accepted solution.

Comment: @Elyum check my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Buffer layer C with a very small value, then it works. I used 0.01 m as buffer distance. Buffer again with the negative of it (-0.01) to get back the initial shape, but without the gaps contained in layer C.

Comment: On my side, the issue is not on layerC, but on the result of the clip between layerA and layerB. I tried the buffer on the result of the clip without success. I also realise I should have shared the said clipped layer to avoid confusion... live and learn...

Comment: My bad, I did exactly what you said, and it works

Comment: So buffering solved your problem or not? I'm a bit confused. If you run geometry checker on layer C, see see that it has many sliver polygons.

Comment: Yes and no. See next answer plz.

Comment: So I'm quite confused. Can you state a bit clearer what works and what not?

Comment: @Babel it seems that the OP had some invalid geometries (check my answer), that needed to be fixed. Then your solution worked.

Answer (score 4):

Apologies for cluttering the answer section, but this is geared towards why the OP might be running into some problems and may lend a hand towards others troubleshoot similar problems.

The OP has some odd geometry types within their dataset. For example `LayerC id==27` is `Class NoneType`. You can find these underlying issues by using [geopandas](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/) within a python script.

```
# python 3.10.9
import os
os.environ['USE_PYGEOS'] = '0'
import geopandas

# Load the file
file = geopandas.read_file("C:/Users/zleslie/Downloads/layerC.shp")

# Iterate through geometries and track the id with enumerate
for i, geom in enumerate(file.geometry):
    try:
        geom.geom_type
    except:
        print(type(geom))
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you run `select by expression` on your faulty layer (in this case layer C), using `$area<1`, thus selection all sliver geometries. Then delete those.

This can be implemented in a model, probably in a script, too, but the latter is beyond my expertise.

Comment: Good idea, I've used that before, but in this case, it doesn't help...
Also, it is not the layrC that is faulty, it is the result of the clip

Comment: For me it worked with your data @Elyum

Comment: sorry, I edited while you were answering